# How to verify the machine has been power cycle (reboot) in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

We have this quite unusual case where the machine has frozen a few times according to the user, and he has to do a reboot (the off/on button).

We troubleshoot this and we could NOT find any issue with the OS and application.

As we could not replicate the issue as well as seeing the issue as the user is a remote user and only once while he's in the office, how to verify this reboot that he has done?

We looked the Event Viewer **ID 6005 and 6006** in Windows Log/System and the last time happening was 9 January 2019. He claimed that happened a few times yesterday (2019-02-19)) or last week?!?!

Environment:

- Windows 10 Professional
- Toshiba KIRA

Thanks

Comment: If it freezes it probably won't log anything.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia .. true BUT the Event ID 6005 (The EVent log service was started) will tell whether the machine restarted OR not after the crash/freeze .... I didn't see any proof for that ?!?!

Comment: There are multiple ways to check the last reboot time or the computer up time. Event viewer is one of them. `wmic os get lastbootuptime` is another. Google will show others.

Comment: If it freezes all it will log is when it is started again 6005, nothing will be logged when it freezes.